Ubuntu won't start up
Yesterday i had my computer pluged in to a tv screen and i watched a series. I fall asleep and forgot everything open as it was and pluged in (it happens to me sometimes). I woke up a few hours later and saw on the screen that the background is a image from the series that i watched... Like someone push pause but it is a background picture. I also had some files that are saved on my desktop but there were no icons on the left side like usually and no upper line with the time and stuff. I tried to click 'tab' to show up the pages that are open but nothing happened, i also tried to click on the 'windows' tab on the keyboard but no manue opned.
I turned off the computer and tried to turn on again but it won't start up. There in the logo of the company (lenovo), and after that there are some lines running quick (can't see what it says) and then only black screen and a - blinking.
Whould really like to get help to know how to fix it and figgure out what happened suddenly.
